# How to call "this" from an anonymous method?(flex, as)

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

This is my code:

```
public function setPaneContent(names : Array, parent : AbstractPane) : void  {
//....

 okButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function okMouseClickHandler(e : Event) : void {
                parent.addNewPane(valuesPane, parent);


                    PopUpManager.removePopUp(/*need to put "this"*/);

                });
 //.....
}
```

When i call `PopUpManager.removePopUp(/*need to put "this"*/);`, i need to make a reference at the object that contains this method(this).

So my question is: "Is it possible to make a reference at **'this'** keyword within an anonymous method?"

Comment: store this to some variable: _this = this in the constructor, use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

store `this` to some variable: `_this = this` in the constructor, use _this. (it works in javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to, you can call another function

```
public function setPaneContent(names : Array, parent : AbstractPane) : void  
{

     okButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, 
                    function okMouseClickHandler(e : Event) :void 
         {
            parent.addNewPane(valuesPane, parent); 

            // call the remove function where you can reference "this"
            remove();
         });
         //.....
}

private function remove():void
{ 
    PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
}
```